# Call an action from a Html.Dropdown onchange event in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdown

I'm trying to call the action in the controller when the dropdown selected item changes. Here is the code I am using but it is not working.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("UserID", null, new { @onchange = "location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'" })
```

What is the correct syntax? I tried to call a javascript function and it works.

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserID", null, new { @onchange = "leaveChange(this);" })
```

leaveChange(control) is my javascript function.

However, I am unable to invoke the action of the controller. Also, How do I then pass the value of the selected item to the action?

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to that action on the change event ? Why not use a link for that instead of the SELECT element change ?

Comment: @Shyju that is what I ended up doing. The change event of jquery redirects to that action. However I am wondering if there is a more direct way of doing it.

Comment: But for navigating to another page, a link is more appropriate ? Why do you want to bring a SELECT element in that ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call a C# method inside the `htmlAttributes` object where it expects a key value pair. Instead you could execute the Url.Action method and set the result(the url) on a parent element's data attribute and read from that in your javascript code

```
<div data-submit-url="@Url.Action("ApplyVacation","Jobs")">
    @Html.DropDownList("UserID",)
</div>
```

and in the change event, read it

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#UserID").change(function ()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        var url = $this.parent().data("submit-url") + "?userId=" + $this.val();
        window.location.href = url;
    });

});
```

When user make a selection on the SELECT, this code will navigate to the `/Jobs/ApplyVacation` url with querystring key `userId` and the selected option value as the value of that. Update the names as needed based on your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing @ before onchange

```
 @Html.DropDownList("UserID", null, new { onchange = "location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did

```
 @Html.DropDownList("UserID", null,new {@id = "leve" })
```

Jquery code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                $('#leve').change(function () {
                    var url = "/UserRoles/TellMeDate";
                    var name = $('#leve').val();
                    $.get(url, { parameter: name }, function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    });


                })

            });         




        </script>
```

Controller:

```
public string TellMeDate(string parameter)
    {


            return DateTime.Today.ToString() +"-->>>"+ parameter + "!!!!";


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
onchange = "location.href='" + @Url.Action("AdmissionRequirement", "Profile") + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `parameters` to `action` you can use

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserID", null, new { onchange = "location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", 

    new {name = "Test param", category = "Test1"})'" })
```